# Как написать функцию для экранирования слеша и кавычек на JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

Как экранировать слеш и кавычки на JavaScript?

Comment: Ответ на ваш вопрос можно найти [тут](https://learn.javascript.ru/string)

Comment: А зачем вам? Вы случайно не пытаетесь _так_ организовать защиту от XSS? Какая ваша настоящая задача?

Comment: нужно передать json для последующего сохранения в базу

Comment: Ну, а зачем экранировать? Я надеюсь, вы не собираете JSON-строку _вручную_?

Comment: ну вообще-то в этом месте-да(( я использовал вообще JSON.stringify , но данные не экранировались

Comment: `JSON.stringify` — это правильное решение. То, что он выдаёт, и нужно класть в базу. А вот если вы **потом** вставляете значение из базы в HTML-код, здесь нужно экранирование. Но это уже не задача javascript'а, а должна выполняться на server side. Потому что доверять js на стороне пользователя всё равно нельзя.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Например, вот так:

`\/`, `\"` и `\'`.

Comment: Это понятно. Я имел ввиду функцию для экранирования

Comment: Вот на этот ответ гляньте http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24816/escaping-html-strings-with-jquery/12034334#12034334 Свой массив замен прописать прописать и все.

Comment: А есть функция, что б просто добавляла \ перел символом? нужно что-то типа такого, но это не работает:   var entityMap = {
    ' " ': '\"',
    " ' ": '\'',
    "/": '\/'
  };

Comment: Вот что наваял: alert("мама 'мыла\" /раму/".replace(/(["'\/])/g, "\\"+"$1"));

Comment: Спасибо. То что надо)))